# Does mDNSResponder have a plugin system for alternative name resolution schemes?

Tags: macos, dns, mdns

I'm not really sure where to start looking for guidance on this idea, so I figured stackoverflow is a good place to start.

I'd like to add alternative name resolution mechanisms beyond server-based DNS. (I'm hoping to get namecoin resolution without the need for an actual DNS server.)

I know that mDNSResponder is now responsible for all DNS resolution, not just "Bonjour" mDNS lookups, so that seems like a reasonable place to hook in.

Any guidance on this approach? I'll take links to API documentation, guidance from someone familiar with the mDNSResponder codebase, etc.